# Loading components as soon as possible

Tags: angular, angular-components

A rookie question from someone who started learning Angular.

I am considering using it for a new version of a system that manages order handling.

As an example there will be a route ( *ex: /customers/3425* ) which will load the customer info ( and form for editing ) in one component and underneath this other components conserning the customer. A component with a list of contact persons, a list of ongoing orders, quotations, invoices etc.

Examples of what will get the data for each component :

- getCustomerInfo(3425) *fast*
- getCustomerContacts(3425)
- getOrders(3425)
- getInvoices(3425) *many invoices -> slow*

My question is if I with angular should expect it to show the fastloaded customer-info very fast and then the other components as soon as they are done fetching the items from API?

Right now it's running an older asp.net forms solution that doesn't even show the customer until it is done loading all invoices, which in some cases takes a long time, and thats what I would like to make different. A lot of times we don't even need to wait for the invoices to list in a customer view - if we just need to add a contact, create an order or something else.

Comment: I'd say that's the default behavior in Angular. The app and the data are loaded separately. What data is available will be rendered.

Comment: Thats what i expected / hoped for. Thanks!